# Configuring Wireless ADSL 2+ router for static IP

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have the following

1. Binatone DT845W wirless ADSL2+ router
2. An ethernet port with static ip which provides access to the internet

**Problem:**
I want to configure internet access via the router, so that I can connect multiple devices to the internet via the router. I can connect directly using my laptop to the ethernet port (2). The laptop runs Ubuntu 10.04. The ISP has provided a static ip, subnet, gateway and dns server addresses.

I am unable to configure the ADSL router. Earlier I was using it seamlessly with a incoming DSL connection. I have no idea how to configure it using the incoming ethernet port.

**EDIT**

The router has one pot for DSL, four ethernet ports and a wireless antenna (Nothing specifically like a WAN port). It has indicator lights for the DSL, WAN, Ethernet port, Power and Internet. When I used to connect via the DSL line, the DSL, WAN and Internet lights would flicker. However, now only the WAN light does so, no DSL and no Internet lights!! :(

I tried connecting the input ethernet to one of the lan ports of the router, put in the configurations for static ip in the router. Still the status displays as 'Not Connected. ADSL Link Failure'.

Can this device even do what I want it to do? Or does it need a DSL input to work?? If this device is not capable of doing such a thing, can somebody please point out a device which can do this (both is even better!!).

Can somebody please please help me out??

I will be eternally grateful!!!

Comment: Do you still have an adsl/adsl2 connection? If so, you will need to use the adsl wan port. Otherwise, if the router allows, you will need to disable that wan input and use the Ethernet WAN option. You will then configure this in your router's WAN settings with the gateway, mask and IP that your ISP provided. If your router does not offer the option to use any other WAN input than the adsl, you will need to get a new router. Unfortunately, I was unable to find details on that specific router.

Comment: @MaQleod No I dont have a adsl connection now. Also there is no port marked as WAN on the device. Please see the edit.

Comment: Then you can only use this router as an ADSL router or a simple switch. That WAN port will only accept ATM signaling, not Ethernet.

Comment: Is it so :((??? Can you please suggest a device which can do what I want to do and also connect via a DSL line?

Comment: If you have a separate ISP device (for any type of connection) then all you need is a standard router (dlink, linksys, netgear, airlink101, belkin, buffalo, etc). Those all will take standard Ethernet in and you can set the IP to whatever you want (ie whatever static details your ISP provides).

Comment: Do you specifically know of something which can work both on the Ethernet input as well as the DSL input?